# Codeigniter - URI routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I have a website and a dashboard. I want my website to have following uri scheme:

```
https://example.com
https://example.com/features
https://example.com/pricing
```

...

So the above is the default behaviour.

For Dashboard, I want all the pages to have 'app' in the url, like:

```
https://example.com/app/dashboard or https://example.com/app/       (for dashboard)
https://example.com/app/settings
https://example.com/app/account
https://example.com/app/products
...
```

Now, one way to achieve it for dashboard is to re-route all the possible dashboard urls, like

```
$route['app'] = "dashboard";
$route['app/dashboard'] = "dashboard";
$route['app/products'] = "products";
$route['app/services/api/custom/(:any)'] = "api/custom/$1";
...
```

Is there a better solution, as I don't want to do it for so many possible URLs

**I also want to prevent access to dashboard urls without the "app" in the url, so**

```
https://example.com/dashboard
```

should be an treated as invalid url. To achieve that I have following check in the constructor

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/app') !== 0)       // "!==" is must in this case
{
    show_404();
}
```

Comment: could this help `$route['app/(:any)'] = "$1";`

Comment: you should create a controller called 'app' and create a function for each page name in that controller which should be routed to automatically

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$route['app'] = 'dashboard';

// Add anything specific here before the last line, i.e.
// $route['app/specific'] = 'other/controller';
// $route['app/specific/etc'] = 'other/controller/etc';

$route['app/(.*)'] = 'dashboard/$1';
```

Anything that is not defined in the route will still route through the `dashboard` controller.

Comment: My dashboard controller only handles the dashboard page of the dashboard. How does your solution really help?